# Can we decide to get rid of [decisions]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [decisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decisions) currently has 30 questions, no tag excerpt and is used for all kinds of decisions: [design-decisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-decisions) (also a vague tag), technical decisions, decision tables. Not surprisingly, since users come here with a problem and then can use the answers to *decide* how to solve them. So it's a quintessential [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Thoughts?

Comment: Burn it with fire.

Comment: [status-completed].

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't dare such a mass operation at once, but I'm glad somebody has the guts.

Comment: I think @RobertHarvey beat me to it. I looked through it after you posted this, figured it was good, and was just waiting until I had some time.