# Can we also get rid of [design-decisions]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Motivated by [Glorfindel's last meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/can-we-decide-to-get-rid-of-decisions), I checked the tag [design-decisions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-decisions) as well. It is currently used for only 21 questions.

However, I think half of the on-topic questions on this site fall into the category of making some design decisions. So the tag seems to be too unspecific to be useful, and I wonder if it should be removed, too?

For some of those questions, it may make sense to replace the tag by the [design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag?

Comment: I think this is good. I'll start taking a look when I've got some more time, unless someone beats me to it. If anyone does, feel free to flag anything that should be closed/deleted and I can handle those more easily.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, its done, I burned down the house. Please mark my question as status-completed.